# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, pls-00103

i am trying to run this code but it gives me an error in "THEN", i have checked all the code line by line and it appears that the error is in the if statement but i double checked it.

i am trying to compare the time of the accident so i can be able to send the ambulance to the the accident which happened first. i would appreciate your help

```
`create or replace function get_loc return location is
max NUMBER;
CURSOR accident_records IS
SELECT * FROM NEW_ACCIDENT;
accidentRec NEW_ACCIDENT_TYPE := NEW_ACCIDENT_TYPE (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
ac_loc LOCATION := LOCATION (NULL,NULL);
type New_accident_rec_type is record
(
id number,
loc location,
TIME NUMBER,
SITUATION varchar2(60)
);
new_accident_rec New_accident_rec_type;
BEGIN
max:=0;
OPEN accident_records;
LOOP FETCH accident_records INTO new_accident_rec;
EXIT WHEN accident_records%NOTFOUND;
IF new_accident_rec.situation='not handled' then
IF new_accident_rec.time>max THEN
max:=new_accident_rec.time;
accidentRec.time:=new_accident_rec.time;
ac_loc:=new_accident_rec.loc;
END IF;
IF new_accident_rec.time<max THEN
ac_loc:=NULL;
END IF;
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE accident_records;
dbms_output.put_line ('The time of Accident is: '||accidentRec.time || 'The location of the accident is: ' ||ac_loc);
RETURN ac_loc;
END;`
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a local variable named `max`, which conflicts with the Oracle `MAX` aggregate function.

The error arises because Oracle thinks a `(` character is coming after the `max`, but it sees `THEN` instead.  The full text of the error I see is

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
22/42    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         (
```

(I may have reformatted your code before I ran it; don't worry if the line/column numbers don't match.)

In PL/SQL it is normally a good idea to prefix local variables with `l_` or `v_`.  As well as avoiding Oracle built-in functions like `MAX`, it also helps you avoid name clashes with column names that happen to be the same as your local variable.

Hopefully if you rename your `max` variable to `l_max`, your compilation error should go away.